# 403 forbidden error occurs on ajaxfilemanager

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

How can I fix 403 forbidden error? I've been using ajaxfilemanager with tinymce in many servers but on this one i got 403 error. I have no idea how to fix 403 forbidden error. 
Help much appreciated and needed soon.

p.s i don't have access to php.ini file. Ans server is Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)

Answer (score 0):

1&1 managed server?

Read this:
https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/400928-Before-ok-but-today-Erro-403-with-friendly-url

http://xenforo.com/community/threads/error-403-forbidden.31398/

Comment: thanks i was testing this is the url which get that error, without these get varibles no 403 error comes.
http://www.domain.org.uk/folder/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/ajaxfilemanager/ajax_image_thumbnail.php?view=thumbnail&path=../../../../tt.jpg
if i change this to 
 &path=tt.jpg  or &path=../tt.jpg it works. but if i put &path=../../tt.jpg gets 403 error. Have any clue?

Comment: and i have deleted .htaccess but no luck and i don't have access to server logs..